# Is migrating from RDS to Elastic MapReduce + Hive the right choice?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, hive, amazon-emr

First of all I must put clear that I am a newbie and excuse myself if I don't use the correct terminology in my question.

This is my scenario:

I need to analyze large quantities of text like tweets, comments, mails, etc. The data is currently inserted into an Amazon RD MySQL instance as it occurs.

Later I run and R job locally using RTextTools (http://www.rtexttools.com/) over that data to output my desired results. At this point it might be important to make clear that the R scripts analyzes the data and writes data back into the MySQL table which will later be used to display it.

The issue I am having lately is that the job takes about 1 hour each time I run it and I need to do it at least 2 times a day...so using my local computer is not an option anymore.

Looking for alternatives I started to read about Amazon Elastic MapReduce instance which at first sight seems to be what I need, but here start my questions and confusions about it.

1. I read that data for EMR should be pulled out from an S3 bucket. If thats the case then I must start storing my data into a JSON or similar within an S3 bucket and not into my RDS instance, right?
2. At this point I read it is a good idea to create HIVE tables and then use RHive to read the data in order for RTextTools to do its job and write the results back to my RDS tables, is this right?
3. And now the final and most important question: Is taking all this trouble worth it vs. running a EC2 instance with R and running my R scripts there, will I reduce computing time?

Thanks a lot for your time and any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I would like to suggest few things.

1. You can totally store data in S3, but you will have to first write your data to some file (txt etc) and then push it to S3. You cannot put raw JSON on S3. You can probably get the benefit of cloud front deployed over S3 for fast retrieval of data. You can also use RDS. the performance difference you will have to analyze yourself.
2. Writing results back to RDS shouldn't be any issue. EMR basically creates two EC2 instances , ElasticMapReduce-master and ElasticMapReduce-slave which can be used to communicate with RDS.
3. See,I think its worth trying out with EC2 instance with R , but then to reduce the computation time, you might have to go with expensive EC2 instance, or put autoscaling and divide task between different instances. Its just like implementing whole parallel computation logic by yourself, but in the case of EMR , you are getting all this logic of map reduce in itself.  So, firstly you should try with EMR and if it doesn't work out well for your , try with new EC2 instance with R.

Let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, have you ever used HIVE tables? is it worth it to create it using the data in the S3 bucket?

Comment: I am afraid not. But I have seen lot of people doing it, creating HIVE tables from data at S3. I would also recommend s3fuse , by which you could mount local EBS drive to S3. make changes /retrieve locally and it will be also reflected to s3, which you could use for other instances (again mounted). I am doing it for parallel video processing.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider trying EMR.  S3+EMR is very much worth trying out if the 1hour window is a constraint.  For your type of processing workloads, you might save cycles by using a scalable on demand hadoop/hive platform.  Obviously, there are some learning, re-platforming, and ongoing cluster mgmt costs related to the trial and switch.  They are non-trivial.  Alternatively, consider services such as Qubole, which also runs on EC2+S3 and provides higher level (and potentially easier to use) abstractions.

Disclaimer:  I am a product manager at Qubole.